# ofstream error using << operator

Tags: c++, file-io, ofstream

I got error when I use ofstream outputting an double array to a txt file. Here is the code:

```
static void OutpuResults(std::string fileName, double * yCal, int nPtCal)
{
    std::string value;
    double * yCal_local = yCal; 

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(fileName.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i < nPtCal; i++)
    {
        outfile<<yCal_local[i]<<std::endl;
    }

    delete[] yCal_local;
    outfile.close();    
}
```

Error occurs at `outfile<<yCal_local[i]<<std::endl;` where i = 0, and `yCal_local[i]` is 0.000000 as a double. Makes no sesne to me.

Here is the definition of fileName:

```
std::string fileName = "d:\\inter.txt";
```

and here is the definition of yCal:

```
int nPtCal = 256;
double * yCal = new double[nPtCal];
```

I am wondering where I did wrong? Any suggestion is appreciate it.

Edit:
It does not have a problem when compling it, but error occurs when it is running.
Here is the error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x75f5812f in ppppp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0028f754..
```

And here is the code showing up when the program returns from error:

```
void __cdecl _unlock (
        int locknum
        )
{
        /*
         * leave the critical section.
         */
        LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

Edit:

Here is all the code:

```
#include "pppp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


static void show_usage(std::string name)
{
    std::cerr << "To use ZoomCal:\n " << "ZoomCal.exe inputfile -options\n"
              << "options:\n"
              << " -l: linear\n"
              << " -c: cubic"<< std::endl;
}

static void LoadData(std::string fileName, double* y)
{
    std::string value;
    double * y_local = y;
    char *cstr = new char[fileName.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(cstr, fileName.c_str());

    std::ifstream infile;

    infile.open(cstr);

    if (!infile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr<<"File loading failed. Double check if file exists in the same folder as ZoomCal.exe"<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int col = 10;
    while ( infile.good() )
    {
        getline ( infile, value, ',' ); // read a string until next comma: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

        if (count % col == 0)
        {
            if (count != 0)
            {
                *y_local = std::atof(value.c_str());
                y_local++;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    //delete [] cstr;
    //delete y_local;
    infile.close();    
}

static void OutpuResults(std::string fileName, double * yCal, int nPtCal)
{
    std::string value;
    //double * yCal_local = yCal;   

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(fileName.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i < nPtCal; i++)
    {
        outfile<<yCal[i]<<std::endl;
    }

//  delete[] yCal_local;
    outfile.close();    
}

double * LinInterp(double * y, int nPt, int nPtCal)
{
    double * yCal = new double[nPtCal];
    double * tmp = new double[nPtCal-5];
    int interval = 10;
    double * pPiece = new double[interval];
    double f2, f1, m, b;
    int x2, x1;

    std::memset(yCal, 0, sizeof(double)*nPtCal);
    tmp += 6;

    for (int i = 0; i < (nPt - 1); i ++)
    {
        *pPiece = *y; 

        f2 = *(y + 1);
        f1 = *y;
        x2 = (i + 1) * interval;
        x1 = i * interval;

        m = (f2 - f1)/(x2 - x1);
        b = f2 - m * x2;

        for (int k = 1; k < interval; k++)
        {
            pPiece[k] = m * ((i * interval) + k) + b;
        }

        std::memcpy(tmp + (i * interval),  pPiece, sizeof(double)*interval);

        y++;
    }

    std::memcpy(yCal + 6,  tmp, sizeof(double)*250);


    return yCal;

}

double * CubInterp(double * y, int nPt, int nPtCal)
{

    double * yCal = new double[nPtCal];
    std::memset(yCal, 0, sizeof(double)*nPtCal);

    return yCal;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) 
    {
         show_usage(argv[0]);   
         return 1;
    }

    std::vector <std::string> sources;
    std::string destination;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) 
    {
        std::string arg = argv[i];
        if ((arg == "-h") || (arg == "--help")) 
        {
            show_usage(argv[0]);
            return 0;
        } 
        else if ((arg == "-d") || (arg == "--destination")) 
        {
            if (i + 1 < argc) 
            { // Make sure we aren't at the end of argv!
                destination = argv[i++]; // Increment 'i' so we don't get the argument as the next argv[i].
            } 
            else 
            { // Uh-oh, there was no argument to the destination option.
                std::cerr << "--destination option requires one argument." << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }               
        }   
        else 
        {
             sources.push_back(argv[i]);
        }                            
    }

    int nPt = 26;
    double * y = new double[nPt];

    LoadData(sources[0], y);

    int nPtCal = 256;
    double * yCal = new double[nPtCal];

    yCal = LinInterp(y, nPt, nPtCal);

    std::string fileName = "D:\\inter.txt";
    OutpuResults(fileName, yCal, nPtCal);

    getchar();
    return 1;     
}
```

Comment: is it compiler error? can you show us the error?

Comment: Sorry, let me edit a little more.

Comment: You have more problems than that: To start with you say you want to write to a text file, but you open the file in binary mode. The most serious problem might be the `delete` at the end of the function though, especially if you want to use the array you pass to the function after the call.

Comment: What's the error?  Also, creating yCal_local doesn't do what you think.  When you call delete [] yCal_local, you are in fact freeing the memory that yCal points to, since yCal and yCal_local have the same value.  If you try to access the memory after OutpuResults returns, you should get an error.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: So if I want to overwrite every time, what mode should I use?

Comment: @DanHook:So how do I do this?

Comment: The default mode flag will overwrite the file, and set text mode.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:Thanks. I actually have tried different mode, but they all give me same error.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is right. remove the     'delete [] yCal_local'

Comment: You're showing too little of your code.  Your error is related to allocating and deallocating memory incorrectly.  First, try getting rid of the delete line and if that doesn't work, show more of your code including the OutpuResults call.

Comment: @DanHook: I am simply change writing destination from "d:\\inter.txt" to "c:\\inter.txt", and it works. So I guess it is something like read only setup on d:\ drive that prevents the writting from happening.

Comment: But my folder is unchecked with "read only", and why this is still happening?

Comment: @DanHook: I pasted all the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I got where I did wrong:

```
tmp += 6;
```

My program is to interpolate a array of 26 elements to 256 elements. But the first 6 elements of the interpolated array have to be 0; So I created a new array with length being 256-6 = 250;

```
double nPtCal = 256;
double * tmp = new double[nPtCal-5];
```

But somehow, I also moved this tmp pointer by 6. I guess it would be right if I created an array with length being 256; So no surprisingly the error occurred. Because when the operation fills 256-6 = 250 elements, if the pointer already points to the 6th elements out of the total 250, then it will eventually be out of range because I will basically move the pointer 250 times to process all the 250 elements in the new array.
That is why I kept getting error. I thought it was because some file IO, but now I think not.
Thanks for all your help. Very appreciate it.